# How to make apt-cache, apt-get into one command?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, package-management

In Ubuntu 11.04 or 10.04, how can I make the `apt-get`, `apt-cache` all in one `myapt` so that I can simply use one only, like in Fedora?

For example:

```
myapt search yum   # same as apt-cache search
myapt remove yum   # same as apt-get remove
myapt install yum  # same as apt-get install
```

Any idea how to do alias for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a script with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash

command="$1"; shift

case $command in
  add|depends|dotty|dump|dumpavail|gencaches|madison|pkgnames|policy|rdepends|search|show|showpkg|showsrc|stats|unmet|xvcg)
    apt-cache "$command" "$@"
    ;;
  autoclean|autoremove|build-dep|check|clean|dist-upgrade|dselect-upgrade|install|purge|remove|source|update|upgrade)
    apt-get "$command" "$@"
    ;;
esac
```

Suppose you call it `myapt`. Then, to still having the benefit of bash completion, you need to add the following lines to `~/.bashrc`:

```
_myapt() {
  _apt_get
  tt=("${COMPREPLY[@]}")
  _apt_cache
  COMPREPLY+=("${tt[@]}")
  return 0
} &&
complete -F _myapt $filenames myapt
```

Unfortunately `$command` should precede any options, but seems that bash completion do not works for options that follow command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use alias for that, but you could use bash to create a script.
Now I'm no bash scripter, so I wouldn't be able to tell you the exact code for accomplish that, but what you could do is something like **(this is just pseudocode, sort of, so don't expect it to work!!!)**:

```
var action
var input
get action, input
  if action == search
    then do apt-cache search input
  if action == remove
    then do apt-get remove input
  if action == install
    then do apt-get install input
```

Keep in mind you can write the script (or even a compiled application) in what ever language you are comfortable with, such as python or ruby for example, it does not have to be bash.

**Again, remember my example is just *pseudocode***.